# which one to use placeholder and text property in UItextfield?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I noticed that there are two NSString propery in UItextfield class Placeholder and text.
 What is the difference between them and which one to choose one over the other?
 And what is the reason why they both exist ?? 
Thank you in advance ~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *placeholder   Description     The
>   string that is displayed when there is no other text in the text
>   field. This value is nil by default. The placeholder string is drawn
>   using a 70% grey color.

Usually placeholder is used to place something like "Please enter your password here".

To get UITextField's text you should use `text` property.

```
firstTextField.text = "NickName";
secondTextField.placeholder = "Password";
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply btw sir, So, there seems to have two layers..? and how does only text object get the input from the field even though there might be placeholder object sitting there..? or am i missing some huge concept..?

Comment: Placeholder is shown only if `text` property is nil or an empty string. You should just create a simple application and try it.